# Simple for loop itration dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Following are the two columns(Table is given below) and apply simple for loop so that values that matches other column should appear in front of it.

`miles type  year
12   ford   2015
13   amc    2016
14   toyota 2014
15   ford   2013`

```
modelclass=set(d['type'] for d in mpg)
miles=set(m['miles'] for m in mpg)
for d in modelclass: 
???
```

output should be:

`[('ford',12),('amc',13),('toyota',14),('ford',15)]`

Comment: Can you provide full code? I think you want to do `for k, v in zip(modelclass, miles):`. But why do you use `set`? `set` is not ordered data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but you can get the desired output with

```
result = [(i['model'], i['mpg']) for i in mpg]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a list of dicts then

```
mpg = [ {'mpg' : 12,  'model': 'ford',  'year' : 2015 }, 
  {'mpg' : 13,  'model': 'amc',  'year' : 2016 }, 
  {'mpg' : 14,  'model': 'toyota',  'year' : 2014 }, 
  {'mpg' : 15,  'model': 'ford',  'year' : 2013 },
]

list(map(lambda x: (x['model'], x['mpg']), mpg))
```